# Cannot set Powershell ExecutionPolicy for CurrentUser

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Here is a sample of the commands I am running:

```
PS C:\> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List 

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted


PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
PS C:\> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

I want to set the `CurrentUser` to `Unrestricted`, but I can't seem to do so. I checked for group policies in place as outlined in [this MSDN document](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347641.aspx), but didn't find anything that was configured.

Any clue as to how I can set this?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. It works as intended on my machine. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @briantist It's a Windows 10 bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Windows 10. I had to create the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell` and create a string value in that key called `ExecutionPolicy` with the data `Unrestricted` before it would work. Even then, I can't seem to change it without modifying the registry.

Comment: The only one that helped. Do you know why `Set-ExecutionPolicy` doesn't work?

Answer (score 12):

Like all the others have said this seems to be a bug in preview build of Windows 10. I got it to work by simply providing the -Force parameter.

**Setting for Local Machine:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
```

**Setting for Current User:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a more generalized powershell policy issue than the OP had, but a combination of answers found here and elsewhere ended up being needed for my Win10 Anniversary Edition to correctly update its policies:

1) Make sure this registry entry exists and is set to the lowest security level that you want to allow: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell` 
 `Name:ExecutionPolicy` `Type: REG_SZ` `Data:Unrestricted` 

2) Make sure this registry entry exists and is set to the lowest security level you want to allow: `HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell` 
 `Name:ExecutionPolicy` `Type: REG_SZ` `Data: Unrestricted` 
3) Update your Group Policy by running `gpedit.msc` and navigate to `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows PowerShell`
 
Select `Turn on Script Execution`, then Edit `policy setting` with `Enabled` and in the box below it that says `Execution Policy`, set it to `Allow All Scripts`

After you've done all that, you can use ddcruver's answer by force-updating your policies depending on what you want. If you set your policies to Unrestricted, I would advise setting all the settings that populate from `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` to something more restrictive, like `RemoteSigned`, as malicious powershell scripts are one of the leading causes of memory-based Windows malware.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the bug in my installation of Windows 10. I simply went through the installation using VMWare Workstation 11 and built out a VM. I ran the following without making any changes prior to it:

[image]

In case you want to know the Version of Windows 10 I have: `10.0.10074`

Comment: I see the unexpected behavior described by OP. Windows 10 Enterprise build 10130.

Comment: If that is the case then you should submit the bug through Connect or see if it has already.

Answer (score 0):

You must run powershell with elevated mode before change execution policy

Comment: That doesn't fix the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Registry Key located at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell
```

was set to `RemoteSigned`. Setting the value to `Unrestricted` has worked for me.

Comment: And this is the same as in first answer, isn't it?